# How many zoom levels are out there in Google Map

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2

As far as I know, `MKMapview` has infinite numbers of zoom level. You pretty much can zoom in and out at any distance.

My friend that works in Android says that `MKMapview` has 10 zoom level.

Which one is right?

here is [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are right. While Google Maps has a fixed number of zoom levels for the image tiles used by the `MKMapView`, the `MKMapView` will select the correct zoom level/interpolate between them as necessary.

Also, the fact that the `MKMapView` uses Google Maps is an implementation detail that will  be changing in the next version of iOS. In iOS 6, the map will be constructed from vector images and there truly will be an infinite number of zoom levels.